# Why asp.net web api return a action after insert data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

This is function to insert a record had generated by VS2019 when add a controller:

```
      // POST: api/Students
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(Student student)
        {
            _context.Students.Add(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return  CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = student.Id }, student);
        }
```

I can't understand Why it using `CreatedAtAction` to return `student`, why it not direct return object `return  student;`?

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asynchronous-action-1), given an example:

> A 201 status code is generated by the CreatedAtAction method when a product is created. In this code path, the Product object is provided in the response body. A Location response header containing the newly created product's URL is provided.

So, not only does it return the object, but it also includes the url where the new resource can be found.

Comment: if direct return object, It can not still  insert yet?

Comment: Sure, you can change it to return the object, if you do not want to include the location. It will stil update the database